# Reforming Table/Entity using SQL or Linq to Object

Tags: sql, linq

I'm trying to normalize table A which contains column Name with names concatenated and separated by "/" into table B where name are split into rows and State are copied into the new rows. I googled and tried w/o success, kindly help.

TABLE-A

| Name | State |
| --- | --- |
| Ken/Terri/Roberto | New York |
| David/Ken | Chicago |
| Kevin/John/Mary | New Jersey |

TABLE-B

| Name | State |
| --- | --- |
| Ken | New York |
| Terri | New York |
| Roberto | New York |
| David | Chicago |
| Ken | Chicago |
| Kevin | New Jersey |
| John | New Jersey |
| Mary | New Jersey |

Comment: You need to tell a lot more than "I googled and tried". Also, why did you tag [linq]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use combination of [`SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0), with [`Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0) and [`Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0)

**Input**

```
var tableA = new []
{
    new {Name = "Ken/Terri/Roberto", State = "New York"},
    new {Name = "David/Ken", State = "New York"},
    new {Name = "Kevin/John/Mary", State = "New York"}
};
```

**Linq**

```
var result = tableA.SelectMany(x =>   //Flatten the given sequence
       x.Name.Split('/')              //Split each name by '/'
      .Select(y => new {Name = y, State = x.State}));  //Create Anonymous object for each name
```

[Try it Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7B8eH9)

Comment: @Hussein does it answer your question?

Comment: Brilliant, working perfectly, Thanks